# Number of group homomorphisms from $Z_3$ to $Z_6$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

So, if $Z_3=\{1,x,x^2\}$ and $Z_6=\{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4,x^5\}$, and group homomorphisms preserve group structure, then elements from $Z_3$ can only map to 3 distinct elements from $Z_6$ and thus must map to a normal subgroup...

I'm thinking that the identity $1_{Z_3}$ must map to the identity $1_{Z_6}$.  This leaves two possibilities for $f(x)$.

If $f(x)=x^2,$ then $f(x^2)=f(x)f(x)=x^2\cdot x^2=x^4$

If $f(x)=x^4$, then $f(x^2)=f(x)f(x)=x^4\cdot x^4=x^8=x^2$

I think these are the only two group homomorphisms.  Is this correct?

Comment: Homomorphisms do not _have_ to be injective...

Comment: Can you expound on this?  I'm not sure why this is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You claim that *"This leaves two possibilities for $f(x)$"*, but in fact it leaves *three* possibilities.

As Arthur notes in the comments, group homomorphisms need not be injective. You have given two injective homomorphisms. There is also one non-injective homomorphism.

Comment: Oh, so wait, just the trivial homomorphism would also work, where all map to $1_{Z_6}$?

Comment: Yes @AveryJessup. Trivial homomorphism will also count.

Answer (score 1):

Number of group homomorphisms from $Z_m$ to $Z_n$ is 
  $=gcd(m,n)$
Just take the generator of$ Z_m$ and try to map it to any element whose order divides $m$
Just try to think that since the generator is the seed of the group every homomorphism is dictated by it.because map any other element is actually mapping the generator's power to something.so why not map the generator only

Comment: Okay, but why is this the case?  Can you show it concretely regarding my question?  I am showing two group homomorphisms, but as Arthur pointed out, they need not be injective?

Comment: why the downvote

Comment: Because it was an uninformative and unhelpful comment, far from an answer. It is better now, but still not very helpful. The OP asks a very concrete question and is clearly only just getting to know group homomorphisms. There is no point in such a general statement, without any proof, argumentation or explanation.

Comment: I have hinted how to make homomrphisms let him try